# How use username and password in artifactory-maven-plugin from settings.xml?

Tags: java, maven, repository, maven-plugin, artifactory

[Here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) is a configuration sample of `artifactory-maven-plugin`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>publish</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployProperties>
                            <gradle>awesome</gradle>
                            <review.team>qa</review.team>
                        </deployProperties>
                        <publisher>
                            <contextUrl>https://oss.jfrog.org</contextUrl>
                            <username>deployer</username>
                            <password>{DESede}...</password>
                            <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                            <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                        </publisher>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In that case I have to manual setup `contextUrl`, `userName` and `password`. While standart maven deploy plugin uses such parameters from `setting.xml` (like that):

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <username>username</username>
    <id>server-id</id>
    <password>pass</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

Why jfrom did not use username, url, ... etc. from `setting.xml`? Is there a way to specify only server id without pass and username?

Of course someone can define a properties in settings xml and use them in plugin definition, but in that case these properties can be easily shared with all projects and be outputted by anyone to console during third party builds.

```
<properties>
   <username></username>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) actually suggests a different approach:

> **Keeping your Artifactory publisher credentials secure**
>   If you prefer to keep your Artifactory publisher credentials (`username` and `password`) secure (rather than providing them as free text in the plugin configuration), we recommend storing them as environment variables or system properties and have the plugin read them when needed. Since the usual Maven deploy does not support environment variables or system properties in `settings.xml`, this capability is unique to the Maven Artifactory Plugin.

Hence, indeed the expected functionality of referring to a server id defined in the `settings.xml` is **not implemented**.

---

**One side note**: to enforce good practices, deployments to a Maven Repository should be executed in automated way by a Continuous Integration server (i.e. Jenkins). In this case, the Artifactory plugin for the CI server (i.e. the [Artifactory Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin)) would handle it in a safe way, centralizing this mechanism only in one place (the CI server), behind user management and governance, avoiding accidental actions from local machine. Things that could go wrong otherwise (publishing from local machine):

- code may not be aligned under version control, publishing a harder to troubleshoot artifact
- tests may have been skipped, publishing a potential bug
- build may be only reproducible on that machine, publishing a non re-buildable artifact

Having it in the `pom.xml` may indeed expose it somehow to the issues above (somebody from the team could mistakenly trigger it), while automated processes and gates would insure certain steps.

Comment: So do not use maven jfrog plugin for publications?

Comment: at company level, I would avoid it. I would prefer to delegate the whole mechanism to the CI server, without adding this behavior into the `pom.xml`, which could be mistakenly triggered by a team member (or even the team lead having the credentials and grants on the target server). That is, humans can make mistakes, better to rely on automated processes and gates (which are configured by humans as well, I know :)).

Comment: @Cherry did you finally handle this case? which approach did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that setting up an automated build box and using jenkins/hudson or some similar product would be ideal for this. If you are strapped for time and still want something that has a little bit more security to it, you could consider setting up ssh authentication. documentation below:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SSH+Integration